# Read Excel template using Aspose

Tags: c#, sql, excel, aspose

Let's say I have a class called User:

```
public class User
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

And an Excel sheet where the 1st column is ID, 2nd is Name, 3rd is Email and 4th is Age

Is there a way I can tell Aspose to use this template and populate a list of type User based on this Excel template so then I can save it to a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to import data from a collection of custom objects to a worksheet, you may try to use Cells.ImportCustomObjects method provided by Aspose.Cells APIs. You will provide a list of columns/properties to the method to display your desired list of objects in the worksheet accordingly, see the topic [here](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Import+Data+into+Worksheet#ImportDataintoWorksheet-ImportingfromCustomObjects) for your reference.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.